# Forward GET Request in Proxy Server in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, proxy

I'm writing C code trying to make a very basic proxy server for simply some networking practice. What my goal here is, is to just get a "GET" request from the browser using my proxy and then forward it to the appropriate server, get the information back from the server and then send all the data back to the browser. So far I got the first part to work, i.e. I got the contents of the GET command. Now I'm really stuck on the "forwarding" part. How do i forward the contents of the GET to the place were it's supposed to go, say www.example.com and get that information back? I obviously can't use the same socket descriptor and try use a send command because then I would be sending the GET command back to the browser that was trying to send it out. I've been using Beej's guide and random online tips. This isn't my first networking program but I'm definitely stuck here. I thought I would have to do a DNS look up of the HOST (which is in GET), get the IP and then use getaddrinfor + connect but then connect gives an error that connection is refused. Any tips or hints would be very helpful to me..thanks

edit: I was following another answer here on stack that detailed the steps involved. Basically I'm up to the "Rebuild/Send the new request part"

```
Open port
Listen on port
Get all request sent from the client to that port (maybe make the whole thing multithreaded to be able to handle more than 1 request at a time)
Determine if it is a valid HTTP 1.0 request
Extract the request components
Rebuild the request according to what type of proxy you are
Send the new request
Get the response
Send response to client
```

edit2: HTTP 1.1 Proxy

Comment: You can't do much if the destination server is down. getaddrinfo() may return multiple addrinfo structs, do you check all of them?

Comment: what kind of proxy are you implementing exactly?  An HTTP proxy?  A SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do in an HTTP proxy is implement, i.e. recognize and act on, the CONNECT command. Once you've got that working, everything else is just copying bytes back and forth.

Comment: I was able to receive the CONNECT command, but subsequent calls to recv(2) still result in the same message of "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" when I would expect a GET to come next. What exactly do you mean by "recognize and act on, the CONNECT?"